# SOQL Query on FieldPermissions

Tags: salesforce, apex, soql

I want to list out Read and Write permissions for a few fields on an object from a profile.
I have a profile named CAPI and under the profile I want to find out all the field permissions from Account object. I've constructed this query for it

```
SELECT SObjectType, Field, PermissionsRead, PermissionsEdit FROM FieldPermissions WHERE SObjectType = 'Account' AND Field IN('Name','ShippingStreet','ShippingCity') AND Parent.Profile.Name  = 'capi'
```

But no data gets exported when I execute it. What am I doing wrong? Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, fields in `FieldPermissions` objects follow the `Object.FieldName` pattern e.g. `Account.Phone`.

Second, there is no fields like `ShippingStreet` and `ShippingCity` on Account because they are part of a compound field called `ShippingAddress`.

As for the last, there is no permission to Name field listed in `FieldPermissions` object, as permission to this field depends on object permission.
So your query should look like

```
SELECT SObjectType, Field, PermissionsRead, PermissionsEdit FROM FieldPermissions WHERE SObjectType = 'Account' AND Parent.Profile.Name  = 'capi' AND Field IN ('Account.ShippingAddress')
```

Answer (score 0):

I saw this [reference here](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/engineering/2012/06/using-soql-to-determine-your-users-permissions-2) and think it can help you:

```
SELECT Id, SObjectType, PermissionsRead, PermissionsEdit, Parent.label, Parent.IsOwnedByProfile
FROM ObjectPermissions
WHERE (ParentId
IN (SELECT PermissionSetId
FROM PermissionSetAssignment
WHERE Assignee.Name = 'capi'))
AND
(PermissionsRead = true)
AND
(PermissionsEdit = true)
```